# JavaFX application with JDBC in NetBeans don't start

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

I work on a small educational project - easy java app with database and gui. I work in NetBeans IDE.
For graphical interface I use JavaFX, and as I've testet this part work perfectly fine, but I have some problem with JDBC part (I use JDBC driver for sqlite database, created with DB browser for sqlite). My main application class looks like this:

```java
public class BazaLyoko extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        Database baza = new Database();
        String tytul = baza.getEpisodeName(1);
        
        stage.setTitle(tytul);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    
    
    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

And when I change those lines:

```java
        Database baza = new Database();
        String tytul = baza.getEpisodeName(1);
```

To this (to replace value retrieved from database to a placeholder - I did this to ensure if the error is rather connected with JavaFX or JDBC part)

```
        String tytul = "";
```

Program start without problem, but when I try to use my database application don't start. There isn't any compilation error or anything like that (or maybe I just don't see them, as I'm quite new to this IDE, though I think such things are usually blatantly visible) just no application window appear.

Here's the code for my database class(they both share the same package):

```java
public class Database {
       
    public static Connection conn;
    
    public Database()
    {
        connect();
    }
               
    public static void connect()
    {
        
        String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlite:BazaLyoko.db";
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            if (conn != null)
            {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
                //System.out.println("Nazwa sterownika to " + meta.getDriverName());
                //System.out.println("Stworzono baze danych.");
                
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private ResultSet doQuery(String query) throws SQLException
    {
      Statement stmt = null;

      try
      {
          stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
          return result;
      }
      catch (SQLException e )
      {
          throw new Error("Problem", e);
      }
      finally
      {
          if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
      }
    }
    
    public String getEpisodeName(int nr) throws SQLException
    {
        ResultSet result = doQuery("SELECT tytul FROM Odcinki WHERE numer="+String.valueOf(nr));
        result.next();
        return result.getString("tytul");
    }
}
```

Database of that name is located inside my project directory (i also tried to copy it to package directory but nothing changed), the names of the table and column are correct to and exist a row with value `1` in column `numer`.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Edit:
I manage to get the following Stack Trace:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:BazaLyoko.db
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.printStackTrace(Utility.java:933)
    at bazalyoko.Database.connect(Database.java:46)
    at bazalyoko.Database.<init>(Database.java:26)
    at bazalyoko.BazaLyoko.start(BazaLyoko.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bazalyoko.Database.doQuery(Database.java:57)
    at bazalyoko.Database.getEpisodeName(Database.java:75)
    at bazalyoko.BazaLyoko.start(BazaLyoko.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application bazalyoko.BazaLyoko
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Is your SQL valid... like is numer a column name?  Have you tried debugging this?  I have a feeling you are silently catching an exception.

Comment: You're ignoring exceptions by only printing them out to the console and then continuing as if nothing happened. If you do that in the rest of your application, then you should look at the console of your application for errors. When logging exceptions, use `printStackTrace()`, don't only print their message. For example the way `doQuery` is implemented will close the statement and therefor close the result set before you use it!

Comment: I already wrote that names of tables and column are correct (so yes, numer is a column name **it was already said**).
And the problem is I don't see any console. When i try to start the application ***nothing*** happen, nothing what is visible I mean... and how could be the result closed if it is returned? That's completely anti-intuitive... 
I'll try to use printStackTrace(), but I don't know if I will be able to see it... I don't know there is some special way to turn out the console in NetBeans?

Comment: Ok, when I added this ``printStackTrace()`` i finally get some console output. 
What really confues me is that it say: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:BazaLyoko.db", though I just added the newest JDBC driver for SQLite... I add the while stacktrace to my question